# Fffmpeg mapping audio and video by language

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, transcoding

I want to batch convert these mkv files, they contain more than one language. Instances include: Eng/Ger, Eng/JPN. Sometimes there are multiple video sources within the mkv for whatever reason:

ive tried using:

```
FFMPEG_PATH . ' -i ' . $localFile . ' -sn -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:m:language:jpn -c:v ' . $videoCodec . ' -tune animation -crf 20 -refs 6 -bf 6 -trellis 1 -b_strategy 1 -profile:v high -level 4.0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -ac 2 -flags +aic+mv4 ' . $scale . ' ' . $convertedFilename;
```

This one grabs the first video (this doesnt matter, but i need it to grab one video just in case)

```
-map 0:v:0 -map
```

I don't thing this one works because when i tried it, it grabbed the english one instead so i dont know the issue.

```
0:a:m:language:jpn
```

I could do

```
0:m:language:jpn
```

but then id have to remove: 0:v:0 and sometimes theres a issue where just using the general mapping would encode both video sources so it wold double in file sizes

so how would i just map the audio file while keeping the video mapping?
Fgmpeg is really confusing with this instruction.

Comment: Show your command and full console output for what you've tried.

Comment: what i want to know is does `0:a:m:language:jpn` qualify as a valid mapping parameter?